# How to disable other input when this input OnKeyUp?

Tags: javascript

How to disable other input when this input OnKeyUp ?

When i input data into input  `name="inputid1"` , i want to disabled other input

when i input data into input  `name="inputid2"` , i want to disabled other input

when i input data into input  `name="inputid3"` , i want to disabled other input

when i input data into input  `name="inputid4"` , i want to disabled other input

How can i do this with javascript loop ?

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="form-id" method="post" action="" ENCTYPE = "multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return checkform(this);">
    <input type="text" id="inputid1" name="inputid1" onKeyUp="fn_test1()">
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="inputid2" name="inputid1" onKeyUp="fn_test2()">
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="inputid3" name="inputid1" onKeyUp="fn_test3()">
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="inputid4" name="inputid1" onKeyUp="fn_test4()">
    <br>
    <span id="myplace"></span>
</form>
<?PHP 
    for($i=1;$i<=4;$i++)
        {
?>
<script>
function fn_test<?PHP echo $i; ?>() {
    $("#inputid2").prop('disabled', true);
    $("#inputid3").prop('disabled', true);
    $("#inputid4").prop('disabled', true);
    setTimeout(function(){
        $.ajax
        (
            {
                url: 'test_mm16.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: $('#form-id').serialize(),
                cache: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#inputid2").prop('disabled', false);
                    $("#inputid3").prop('disabled', false);
                    $("#inputid4").prop('disabled', false);
                    $('#myplace').show();
                    $('#myplace').html(data);
                }
            }
        )
    }, 2000);
}
</script>
<?PHP
        }
?>
```

Comment: I don't want to be rude, but consider to read some PHP and JavaScript tutorials. Your code is so obscure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work

```
$('#form-id input').on('keyup',function() {
    $('#form-id input').attr('disabled','disabled'); //disable all
    $(this).removeAttr('disabled'); //enable the one that triggers the event
    doPost();
});



 function doPost() {
     $.ajax({
                    url: 'test_mm16.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: $('#form-id').serialize(),
                    cache: false,
                    success: function (data) {                   
                        $('#myplace').show();
                        $('#myplace').html(data);
                    },
                    always: function() {
                        $('#form-id input').removeAttr('disabled');
                    }         
                }
            )
    }
```

Working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/z4apqjan/

Edited: I put the doPost function to execute the Ajax request.

Comment: This will work for N inputs, so you won't need to specify the number of inputs in the php.

Comment: what it's mean N inputs ?

Comment: I meant Non-predetermined number of inputs, so in one execution you can have 4 and in the next 40, the same code will work

Comment: But where to post to `test_mm16.php` and after success post i want to enable all input.

Comment: on your success function you will enable them with: $('#form-id input').removeAttr('disabled')

Comment: and where this code                 `url: 'test_mm16.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: $('#form-id').serialize(),
                cache: false,
                success: function (data) {`

Comment: do you want to execute ajax on every key-up event? I mean if you type "cow" do you want to send one request con "c" one on "o" and one on "w"?

Answer (score 0):

There are to much messy things in your code, but I've made some corrections for you:

1. You have same names for four input elements, so you will always get `inputid1` param in your `PHP` and I think this is not want you want to achieve.
2. You don't need to bind `keyup` for each element manually in html, better use advantage of `jQuery`, for this purpose I've added `class` attribute to all four inputs with value `strangeInputs`, you can change it respectively as you wish.
3. No need to create functions for each input, you already have enough information which separates the meaning of them.
4. Also after once `keyup` occurs to one of the input elements I think you no longer need `keyup` handler, so we will remove it after first it's been fired with `jQuery`'s `.off` function. **Edit:** but because you send request all the time keyup occurs to the input we should not disable event listener

Finally your simplified code would look like this:

**HTML:**

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="form-id" method="post" action="" ENCTYPE = "multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return checkform(this);">
    <input type="text" id="inputid1" class='strangeInputs' name="inputid1">
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="inputid2" class='strangeInputs' name="inputid2">
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="inputid3" class='strangeInputs' name="inputid3">
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="inputid4" class='strangeInputs' name="inputid4">
    <br>
    <span id="myplace"></span>
</form>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
/**
 * scenario is simple, bind keyup event, when it fires once, 
 * execute desired code and remove keyup listener finally 
 */ 
$(function(){
    $('.strangeInputs').keyup(function(){
        $('.strangeInputs').not(this).prop('disabled', true);

        fn_test_inputs();

        // $('.strangeInputs').off('keyup'); 
        // in the case you send request at once keyup event occurs, 
        // you should not remove listener  
    });
});


function fn_test_inputs() 
{
    setTimeout(function(){
        $.ajax
        (
            {
                url: 'test_mm16.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: $('#form-id').serialize(),
                cache: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    // here enable inputs again
                    $('.strangeInputs').prop('disabled', false);
                    $('#myplace').show();
                    $('#myplace').html(data);
                }
            }
        )
    }, 2000);
}
```

Simple input thing you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/gttv53fg/

Comment: where ajax post to test_mm16.php

Comment: there is `fn_test_inputs()` called inside keyup handler, can't you seE?